# AWS IAM - can a service know the role invoking it?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, ssm, aws-ssm

**Overall goal:**

I am writing a wrapper around the AWS Parameter Store for our micro service environment (all new).  Basically, I'm trying to ease the transition from one service provider to another if we decide to move to Azure, e.g., so only this service would have to be modified.

The idea is that a service on startup could call this service ('config service') to get all configuration settings.

**Problem:**

If we decide to go this route, there may be a desire to still lock down parameters based on IAM permissions (roles/policies).  I am looking for a way in this config service to perhaps grab the user/role calling the config service and pass that through to the Parameter Store, e.g., when calling `ssm.getParameters(...)`.

I've seen [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_passrole.html) page, which allows limiting users to which roles they can pass, so it seems that I can pass the role.  I need to figure out *how* to find that role, though.

If I were using .NET with an ASP.NET site and Windows Authentication, for example, there's an ability to impersonate that user in order to simulate that user's permissions.  (The overall effect being the calling service's permissions limit the parameters it can access.)

I'm using node.js in Elastic Container Service, using the new Fargate luanch type, if that affects the potential answers.

Comment: I did do a console dump of `process`, which includes environment variables, etc., but I didn't see anything in there.

Comment: An EC2 instance can determine the role name via metadata. This is under iam/info and iam/security-credentials. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html

Comment: @JohnHanley I reviewed your link and found a few other ways that will work (namely [this one](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-iam-roles.html) with the `AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI` environment variable).  However, that still means every service has a dependency  on AWS to be able to find its execution role.  My hope was that AWS could pass the info into the config service, so it could be trusted and the dependency only lives in the one service.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to lock SSM parameter for a specific microservice

1. Create and attach IAM role for each ECS task
2. Organise your parameters using `path` notation
3. For each IAM role specify `Resource` to limit access only for a specific path (see [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/managing-secrets-for-amazon-ecs-applications-using-parameter-store-and-iam-roles-for-tasks/)).
   That will allow you to have only specific parameters available per microservice.

PS. if you just want to retrieve the current role being [used](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sts/get-caller-identity.html)

`aws sts get-caller-identity`

Another alternative solution:

1. When calling your `config-service` include a `microservice` name in the request and create IAM roles to match `microservice` name.
2. Use `aws sts assume-role` in your `config-service` to assume IAM role that would be available to the microservice.
3. Lock your `config-service` to assume only allowed roles.

Comment: That's a good point, but potentially a lot of redundancy for step 2.  E.g., location of a common service.  But it all comes down to trade offs, right?   I'm not sure how step 3 applies if I can't get passthrough auth from the calling service to the parameter store (caller -> config service -> parameter store).  I've looked into STS and seeing if the identity would work for pathing, if necessary.  Thanks for the info.

Comment: @ps2goat I added another potential solution

Comment: Yes, the second solution is what I'm currently looking into.